# IE11 Edge mode is not working by default (Included meta tags and doctype)

Tags: internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I'm working on webpage that was built to run on IE7, and now i'm in the process of upgrading the page to run in IE11 Edge mode by default.

What i've did in the page is that i added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I also added this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Test Image Request</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-expand{overflow-y:visible}
    </style>
</head>
```

Now whenever i open the page, the Emulation Panel in IE11 Developer mode says its rendering in IE7!

What did i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! there was `<script>` before `<head>`, moved it after `<head>` and now eveything works fine.